# INSERT new row into database java?

Tags: java, sql

I have the simple following code:

```
try {   
    Main.db.getCon().createStatement().executeUpdate("INSERT INTO qos_qoe (channel_id) VALUES ('vtv1') ");
    Main.db.getCon().createStatement().executeUpdate("UPDATE qos_qoe SET channel_id = 'vtv1' WHERE id = 3 ");

} catch (SQLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The UPDATE command runs well but INSERT command does not. Runs that INSERT command directly in phpmyadmin shows no problem. Where does the problem lie in? 
Thanks for any reply!

Comment: "Does not run" is not enough information. Do you get an exception? If yes which one.

Comment: Sorry! I'm still new to Java so i only know the code can't run if i don't comment the INSERT line.

Comment: Then show us the stacktrace you get if you un-comment the line

Comment: Is there any exceptions thrown in the console?

Comment: Also, I believe you should care sharing the table structure (incl. primary key & unique indexes at least).

Comment: How do you know it doesn't run?

Comment: Maybe the table has more than 3 columns?

Comment: I've made the code as simple as possible yet still have problems with INSERT command.That command runs if i put it in phpmyadmin( sql ) directly. Here's the table:

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qos_qoe` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `channel_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zapping_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `delay` float NOT NULL,
  `jitter` float NOT NULL,
  `plr` float NOT NULL,
  `mos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

Comment: Of course i know it runs or not since i can see the change in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `rated` or `vote_count` is not of char type in the db. Anyway, you should use [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) I'll assume all your variables are Strings

```
String statement = "UPDATE iptv_media_source SET rated = ?, vote_count = ? WHERE channel_id= ? ";
PreparedStatement st = Main.db.getCon().prepareStatement(statement);
st.setString(1, rated);
st.setString(2, vote_count);
st.setString(3, channelId);    
st.executeUpdate();
```